# There has been a critical error on this website for xampp localhost

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

I was trying to build a website on WordPress using xampp localhost, but I got the message saying that there has been a critical error on this website. I didn't even open the website.
can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

in wordpress site shows there has been a critical error on your site, just go to
your site folder and search for `wp-confing.php` file edit the file and search for `WP_DEBUG` turn on means make it value true, after that refresh the site, you can see the actual error, with file path so slove that error your site will fine

Comment: That's wp-config.php.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve been using WordPress for some time, you’ve likely heard of or possibly even encountered its most infamous error: the [White Screen of Death](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-white-screen-of-death/). This startling glitch would cause your entire website, and sometimes even your backend, to load as a blank white page.

In [recent versions of WordPress](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-version/), this blank screen has been replaced with the critical error and the text “There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.”

https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-your-website/

Hope this may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to public_html then wp-content and rename the plugin folder to anything (like 'plugin+'). Now all of your plugins will be disabled. Activate them each one by one until you find the one that makes problems for your work.
If it is fixed, rename your plugin folder back to normal.